# Как использовать Toolbar и BottomNavigationBar в одном activity?

Tags: android

Мне надо добавить в моё приложение кнопку на `AppBar`, в то время как я уже использую `BottomNavigationBar`(от material design). Проблема в том, что `BottomNavigationBar` использует темы типы с `ActionBar`, а `ToolBar` без.

**UI:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bottom Bar конечно хорош, но я бы советовал использовать `bottomNavigationView`. У меня в приложении используется такой же тип навигации. И логика вот в чем: вам нужно сделать "родительскую" активность с `bottomNavigationView` и дальше над `bottomNavigationView` будет контейнер для фрагментов. У каждого фрагмента можно будет навесить все что вам нужно, вплоть до еще одного `bottomNavigationView`. Соответственно вы сможете добавить тулбар в фрагмент и что-то с ним делать на ваше усмотрение. [Вот](https://medium.com/@oluwabukunmi.aluko/bottom-navigation-view-with-fragments-a074bfd08711) есть хороший туториал по работе с фрагментами и нижним меню и [вот](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/bottom-navigation-android-example/). Так же мне не очень понятно почему вы не можете установить тему с тулбаром, вот какая у меня стоит:

```
Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar
```

то есть у вас в активности будет тулбар на который из фрагмента вы сможете повесить нужные вам кнопки. Так же за ненадобностью его можно скрыть:

```
supportActionBar!!.hide()
```

ну и соответственно вы добавите слушатели замены фрагмента и обработку нажатий на пункты менюшки внизу. Сама обработка и подвязка менюшку к тулбару будет происходить из под фрагмента либо из под активности.